# Duplicate chromium repository removal

Tags: apt

Somehow I added this repository someone suggested to install chromium (I am a new user) and now every time I update it shows this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/a-v-shkop/chromium/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/a-v-shkop/chromium/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I remove that repository?

Answer (score 2):

Run the below commands on terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Hey,kudos for that, it worked. Can you please help me with this one too?    
    Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
    Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
What does this mean and how do I correct it?

Comment: Look for it in in 'Software & Updates' under 'Other Software', and remove/untick the relevant ppa - it will look like [this](http://itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Software-Sources-Ubuntu-13.04.jpeg).

Comment: plz post the error report in pastebin.com and then provide the link here.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command in a terminal:

gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Scroll down to the repository that you want to remove.
Delete the line of code.
Save the file and exit.

Update your system with the following command in a terminal:

sudo apt-get update

Comment: info about  PPA's is not stored in  ` /etc/apt/sources.list`.It's on `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Comment: And I read somewhere that it's not supposed to be manually edited?